# Where do I put the filename for the program to read?

Tags: c++, io, readfile

I have a C++ file that I would like to learn from but I am facing difficulty trying to open my text file which contains data to read. I am trying to figure out where do I put my text file.

My code is:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void rFile(string argvFile);
void Init(int i, Chord& newChord);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        cout << "INCORRECT SYNTAX!" << endl;
    } else {
**//I changed the this to rFile("text.txt"); but error too.**
        rFile(argv[1]);
    }

}

void rFile(string argvFile) {

    Chord newChord;

    string inLine;
    ifstream inFile;
**// I got an error trying to put the text file name after argvFile.c_str("text.txt"));**
    inFile.open(argvFile.c_str());

    if (inFile.is_open())
        while (inFile.good()) {
            getline(inFile, inLine);

            }
        } else {
        cout << "ERROR! FOUND NOT FOUND!" << endl;
    }
}
```

Can someone please kindly enlighten me?

Comment: It is not so much *where* you put the file you want to read, but *what path* you pass to those `rFile`, i.e. what value of `argvFile` you pass it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code reads filename from the **program parameters**,

```
 rFile(argv[1]);
```

**argv** is an array of parameters passed to the program during its execution, so for example running

```
 ./prog a b c
```

assigns

```
  argv[1] = "a"
  argv[2] = "b"
  argv[3] = "c"
```

the 0'th element (argv[0]) contains the program name, so in this case

```
  argv[0] = "prog"
```

so in case of your program - once you compile it to the **prog**, you run it through (unix)

```
./prog PATH_TO_FILE
```

or (windows)

```
prog.exe PATH_TO_FILE
```

Comment: Thank you! compile them with G++ and then ./prog filename.txt IT worked! Thanks for enabling me to learn something new!